# How i get child value from firebase database in clicked item

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get value(Red mark) when i clicked specific item..

But problem is, when i clicked item, display all the value(Red mark)..

I need specific value for specific item...

Here is database snapshot:

[image]

```
DatabaseReference dffr=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("CustData").child("UsersInfo")
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
        .child("order");
dffr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String dataKeys="";
        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            dataKeys=dataKeys+child.getKey()+"";
        }
        Toast.makeText(MyCartActivity.this, " "+dataKeys, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide which value your looking for when clicking specific item

Comment: which value do you want?

Comment: Try using query : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like all orders for a user are identified by the date/time at which the user placed that order. In that case you will need to know the date/time of the order they clicked on, to be able to load just that order.

```
DatabaseReference dffr=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
        .child("CustData").child("UsersInfo")
        .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
        .child("order")
        .child("Aug 11,2019, 02:02:38 PM");
dffr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String dataKeys = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        Toast.makeText(MyCartActivity.this, " "+dataKeys, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

So you will need to somehow map the item that the user clicked back to the date/time of the order. You typically do this by keeping both the key and the value when adding the data from the database to the UI, either in a single list or in two separate lists.